# No logra reconocer ningún rostro

Tags: python-3.7, opencv

**Importa cv2 como cv**

```
import cv2 as cv


cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
```

**Desde imagenes abre archivo cascade.xml**

```
faceClassif= cv.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\JOHNNY\PycharmProjects\python_project\imagenes\cascade.xml')
```

**Con el loop while lee cap, cambia a escala de grises BGRGRAY**

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceClassif.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    print(faceClassif)
```

**Llama la funcion rectangulo desde cv**

```
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

**Muestra ventana nombre frame**

```
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

**Destruye ventanas**

```
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Deberias explicar un poco mas el problema.

Answer (score 0):

A ver es una pregunta compleja y estoy de acuerdo con @Ramiro Barone que deberías ampliar toda la información posible. desde mi punto de vista te doi soluciones a varios problemas que veo:

### 1. Estás capturando video?

Estas implantando un  capturador de video, para leer las imágenes por Frame, pero mezclas varias cosas. Yo iría paso por paso, es decir, asegurarte que en principio puedes detectar caras en imágenes. Una vez esto te funcione, intentarlo en video.

### 2. cambiar contrabarras por barras

En ocasiones Python y algunos de sus frameworks, no se llevan bien con las contrabarras de en las direcciones de Windows, por ello se recomienda cambiar las contrabarras (\) por barras (/) en python, como buena práctica de programación.

Una vez hechos estos cambios, y haciendo el algoritmo para leer imágenes te quedarías así.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

faceClassif= cv.CascadeClassifier(r'C:/Users/JOHNNY/PycharmProjects/python_project/imagenes/cascade.xml')

img = cv2.imread("C:/url/de/la/imagen/a/leer.jpg") #Si son varias create un for
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #La pasamos a blanco y negro necesario por el algoritmo cascada.

faces = faceClassif.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 3)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img2 = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### 3. Aun así no me funciona... El brillo.

Si te ves la documentación del clasificador en cascada ([la dejo aquí](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html)) ves como al ser **un algoritmo basado en un principio binario** suele dar problemas con el brillo. Es decir **el algoritmo clasifica los pixeles como blancos o negros en base a un umbral**. Imágenes con mucho brillo hará que todos sean blancos, e imágenes con un brillo muy bajo, harán que todos sean negros.

Para solucionarlo puedes cambiar el brillo de la imagen cuando las lees y ponerle un brillo determinado, esto sin duda mejorará la detección del algoritmo.

Comment: Veo que ese enfoque es más sencillo! Debo asegurarme primero de que pueda detectar el rostro en una imagen y después escalar a video. Gracias a los dos por su ayuda.Voy a intentarlo! Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de ser de ayuda!! Aunque como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow en marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta"  y por qué no, dar un voto positivo (cuando tengas experiencia).